# Why does the CSS loader keep appearing after all the items are loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have been working on an online **[newspaper/blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/Bravecms/pull/16/files)** with *CodeIgniter 3.1.8* and Twitter Bootstrap 4.

I am currently working on loading more posts via AJAX.

By default, the posts are paginated and displayed *12 at a time*, at `http://myblog.com/`, `http://myblog.com/?page=2`, and so on.

##### In the Posts controller (`application\controllers\Posts.php`) I have

```
private function _initPagination($path, $totalRows, $query_string_segment = 'page')
{
    //load and configure pagination 
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url']             = base_url($path);
    $config['query_string_segment'] = $query_string_segment;
    $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
    $config['reuse_query_string']   = TRUE;
    $config['total_rows']           = $totalRows;
    $config['per_page']             = 12;

    if($this->Static_model->get_static_data()['has_pager']){
        $config['display_pages'] = FALSE;
        $config['first_link'] = FALSE;
        $config['last_link'] = FALSE;
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next">';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    }

    if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
        $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
    }
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    
    $limit  = $config['per_page'];
    $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;
    
    return array(
        'limit' => $limit,
        'offset' => $offset
    );
}

public function index()
{
    //call initialization method
    $config = $this->_initPagination("/", $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows());
    $data                  = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['base_url']      = base_url("/");
    $data['pages']         = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories']    = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    $data['search_errors'] = validation_errors();
    
    //use limit and offset returned by _initPaginator method
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);
    $this->twig->addGlobal('pagination', $this->pagination->create_links());
    
    // featured posts
    if ($data['is_featured']) {
        $data['featured'] = $this->Posts_model->featured_posts();
        $this->twig->addGlobal('featuredPosts', "themes/{$data['theme_directory']}/partials/hero.twig");
    }
    
    $this->twig->display("themes/{$data['theme_directory']}/layout", $data);
}
```

In order to load the posts via jQuery Ajax instead, I have:

```
(function($) {

    var currentPage = 1;

    $('.pagination').hide();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
            loadMore();
        }
    });

    function loadMore() {
        $.ajax({
                url: baseUrl + '?page=' + currentPage,
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('.loader').show();
                }
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                $('.loader').hide();
                // Get post from page 2 onward
                if (currentPage >= 2) {
                    var posts = $(data).find('#postsContainer').html();
                }
                // If there are no more posts, hide loader
                //  Otherwise, load more posts
                if (posts == 'undefined') {
                    $('.loader').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#postsContainer').append(posts);
                    currentPage = currentPage + 1;
                }
            });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

#### The problem:

After loading the last post, if I scroll back up (or up and down), the loader is displayed and hidden repeatedly.

---

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this bug?

Comment: If this is the only code that can cause your loader to show and hide then the show and hide lines of code are being executed. Which means your loadMore is being called. So what do you get for the values in your if statement using console.log to display them when this happens?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Have a look at the **[branch](https://github.com/Ajax30/Bravecms/tree/improve_pager)**, it will help understand the issue. There is am .sql export in the root too.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this really related to PHP and AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by initializing the variable `posts` with `null` and making sure that `posts` is not `undefined` before showing the loader:

```
(function($) {

    var currentPage = 2,
        maxPage = $('#postsContainer').data('max-page'),
        posts = null;

    $('.pagination').hide();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var toBottom = $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 25;

        if (toBottom && currentPage <= maxPage) {
            loadMore();
        }
    });

    function loadMore() {
        $.ajax({
                url: baseUrl + '?page=' + currentPage,
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    if (typeof posts != 'undefined') {
                        $('.loader').show();
                    }
                }
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                $('.loader').hide();
                posts = $(data).find('#postsContainer').html();

                if (typeof posts != 'undefined') {
                    $('#postsContainer').append(posts);
                    currentPage = currentPage + 1;

                    if (currentPage > maxPage) {
                        $('#postsContainer').append('<p class="text-center text-muted">No more posts to load</p>');
                    }
                }
            });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

In the controller:

```
public function index()
  {
    //call initialization method
    $config = $this->_initPagination("/", $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows());
    $data                  = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['base_url']      = base_url("/");
    $data['pages']         = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories']    = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    $data['search_errors'] = validation_errors();
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);
    $data['max_page'] = ceil($this->Posts_model->get_num_rows() / 12);

    $this->twig->addGlobal('pagination', $this->pagination->create_links());

    // Featured posts
    if ($data['is_featured']) {
      $data['featured'] = $this->Posts_model->featured_posts();
      $this->twig->addGlobal('featuredPosts', "themes/{$data['theme_directory']}/partials/hero.twig");
    }

    $this->twig->display("themes/{$data['theme_directory']}/layout", $data);
  }
```

In the view:

```
<div id="postsContainer" data-max-page="{{max_page}}">
```